# How do I use Firebug to see the actual contents of a table after its been filtered?

Tags: firebug, tablesorter

For example, after click the 1st cell of of the table on this [page](http://silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2008/10/2/jquery-autofiltering-table), I inspect the html with *View/Page Source using Firefox* and I notice the table identified with `id="myTable"` has all its rows even though only some rows are visible from the normal browser view. I dont understand why there is a difference?

How could I use Firebug to see what data is actually being visible from the browser?

I am trying to understand the structure of what is going on because I would like to see how hard it will be to add code so that after each table filtering of rows there is also a change in the display of linked markers associated to the visible rows on web map (using Google Maps Api).

Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click on one of the cells before it gets hidden (e.g. United States) and select "Inspect Element" from the context menu, that will open the firebug HTML display.  This contains the rendered HTML rather than the raw HTML that is displayed by View Source.

If you then left click on the the first cell to cause the other rows to be hidden, you will then see the HTML on the element highlighted in the firebug HTML view change to "display:none" for the United States row.

Comment: Great answer ...thanks for guiding me threw that issue so well!